# Making an Excel cell additive upon entry (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet where I'm attempting to detect a change in the selection and record the value in the new selection continually. Simultaneously, I want to detect a change in the worksheet within a range. Once this has happened, I'd like to see if the value that was recorded when the selection changed is a number, and add it to the changed value if that was also a number. Essentially, if there's a number in a cell, and I enter a new number, I'd like them to be added together, and to set the cell's value to that sum.

Here's what I have, compiled from a random help article and a couple of ideas from other questions:

```
Dim stuff

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
stuff = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("B3:F49")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) = True And IsNumeric(stuff) = True Then
    Target.Value = Target.Value + stuff
    End If

End If
End Sub
```

However, when I run the code and attempt to make a change, I get "Run-time error '28': Out of stack space" or "Run-time error '-2157417848 (80010108)': Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed". When I attempt to Debug, Excel crashes and has to restart. What am I missing?

Comment: Does it Crash as soon as you debug, or at a certain line of code

Comment: It was when I Debugged and/or hit 0. EganWolf's solution solved the issue.

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark it as solved by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Worksheet_Change` you change the value of a cell and it triggers a `Worksheet_Change`, which change a value of a cell and it triggers a `Worksheet_Change`, which...

Stop it with `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning and set it back to `True` at the end.

---

You can also change this part: `If IsNumeric(Target.Value) = True`

`IsNumeric` returns boolean, so what exactly you do here is `If (True/False) = True`.

`If IsNumeric(Target.Value)` is enough.